# Can i upload a photo to a users group with php sdk?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, photo

My question:  Can it be possible to upload a photo and post it to a user's group?  My APP will upload a photo but i want the user could choose to upload it in his group or page or fanpage, using the PHP SDK.